# NSString substring issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

Here is the code I'm using to separate an NSString into substrings. I don't understand why they are being separated the way they are. I've had instances where it comes out right and some where its just messed up. This method is delegate from a protocol defined in this [project](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort). I feel like its just the way the port is receiving data and the timing with it. I just wanted to make sure I'm not incorrectly using NSString.

I'm trying to get the x, y and z strings into the same array.

```
- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serial didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *listItems = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@", listItems);
```

Output:

```
        2015-04-28 14:15:50.522 GroundStation[69301:3573401] (
    X01,
    Y00,
    ""
)
2015-04-28 14:15:50.522 GroundStation[69301:3573401] (
    Z05,
    ""
)
2015-04-28 14:15:53.675 GroundStation[69301:3573401] (
    X01,
    Y00,
    ""
)
2015-04-28 14:15:53.675 GroundStation[69301:3573401] (
    Z04,
    ""
)
2015-04-28 14:15:58.226 GroundStation[69301:3573401] (
    "X-34",
    "Y-1"
)
2015-04-28 14:15:58.228 GroundStation[69301:3573401] (
    4,
    Z38,
    ""
)
```

Comment: Are you sending the data with the same library or with something else? e.g. the data is sent by some device over serial

Comment: @user43250937 I'm sending the data through uart via usb from a micro controller. I am not using the send methods defined in the library, that I'm using for receiving.

Comment: What is wrong with the output? It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data coming from the serial port really encoded in UTF8 or maybe it's just plain ASCII or something else?

I'd try replacing the second line with this:

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

From your question i got the impression that you are not sure what's coming out of the serial connection, what if it's just a binary protocol?

*Edit:*

After reading your comment, i will do this differently, don't just separate the spaces each time you receive some NSData, as your message can be broken up in multiple pieces, sometimes you just receive X and Y and then Z alone the next time receiveData is called, or as in the last step the value of Y is even broken up in two messages...

You need to store the data received with this callback and process it only when you have a full message, not parsing every time as you are doing now.

You can do two things:

1. Keep a fixed size for this messages e.g. a size of 12 characters: X123Y123Z123, sign included. Put the content you receive in a buffer and parse these 12 chars **only** when you have them. When you've parsed the three X,Y,Z components remove those 12 chars from the buffer and repeat.
2. Add a line terminator (could be any char). Each time you receive some data put it in a buffer, and parse the message **only** when you find a line terminator, when you parse the three X,Y,Z components remove that stuff from the buffer and repeat.

Comment: I do know whats coming out, I'm sending a Ascii characters in the format of X000, where 000 can be any 3 digit number. This is the same for y and z strings. I've tried what you suggested and its still the same result.

Comment: Are you sending from your mcu whole strings or sending each X000, Y000, Z000 block as they are ready? I will do this differently i'm updating the answer.

Comment: Updated, i hope this helps, when i read your question the first time i though it was just an encoding issue, but looking at it that's not the best way to parse stuff coming from a serial interface.

Comment: I ended up just discarding data that wasn't in the correct format and only parse information in the correct format. But if that doesn't work out well later on, I will try the ways you suggested. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Additionally I want to add, that partial transforming the data into a string may potentially conflict with UTF-8 multi bytes sequences, if there are some.